# Drawing a number of HTML canvases according to input value

Tags: html, dom, canvas

I've got an ongoing project where I need to draw a number of HTML canvases (from 1 to 10) according to a number that is typed into the input field.

Perhaps an easier way to go about this would be to already have the canvases in the DOM before drawing, but everything in this function needs to happen dynamically, so the canvases themselves need to be drawn using the JavaScript function.  I was getting better progress with a switch statement but I feel like a for loop would be more appropriate.

For some reason the Fiddle isn't working properly, but the button draws a single canvas just fine in my Cloud9 environment.  Now I just need it to draw a number of canvases corresponding with the input value.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4hys8tr/

HTML:

```
<form action='#' method='get' name=queueform id=queue>
    <div id='queueblock'>
        <div class='formblock'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='cell'>
                <strong>Quantity:</strong><br>
                <hr>
                    <label for='items'>Items:</label>
                    <input id='quantity' size='2' type='text'><br><br>
                    <strong><p>Enter a maximum of 10 items</p></strong>
            </div>
            <div class='cell'><br><br>
                <div>
                    <button onclick='drawCanvas()' id='getitemsbutton' class='button' type='button'>Get Items</button>
                    <button id='clearbutton' class='button' type='reset'>Clear</button>
                    <button id='queuebutton' class='button' type='submit'>Send to Queue</button>
                </div>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
function drawCanvas() {
    var canvasBlock = document.getElementById('canvasblock');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var quantity = document.queueform.quantity.value;
        canvas.id = 'canvas01', 'canvas02', 'canvas03', 'canvas04',
                    'canvas05', 'canvas06', 'canvas07', 'canvas08',
                    'canvas09', 'canvas010';
        canvas.width = 70;
        canvas.height = 70;
        canvas.style.border = '1px solid';
    for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        canvasBlock.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    var c1 = document.getElementById('canvas01');
    console.log(c1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird, JS Fiddle seems bugged at the moment.
Anyways, you were pretty close, however you didn't consider the fact, that you must call the document.createElement() for each canvas you want to create. I rearranged your code a little and replaced the hardcoded id assigning with a dynamic one.

```js
function drawCanvas() {
    var canvasBlock = document.getElementById('canvasblock');
    var quantity = document.queueform.quantity.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = 'canvas'+('0' + i).slice(-2) // generate name dynamically. ('0' + i).slice(-2) is a trick to add a zero if the current number is < 10
        canvas.width = 70;
        canvas.height = 70;
        canvas.style.border = '1px solid';
        canvasBlock.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    var c1 = document.getElementById('canvas01');
    console.log(c1);
}
```

```html
<div id='canvasblock'>
    </div>
    
<form action='#' method='get' name=queueform id=queue>
  <div id='queueblock'>
    <div class='formblock'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
          <strong>Quantity:</strong><br>
            <hr>
            <label for='items'>Items:</label>
              <input id='quantity' size='2' type='text'><br><br>
              <strong><p>Enter a maximum of 10 items</p></strong>
        </div>
        <div class='cell'><br><br>
        <div>
        <button onclick='drawCanvas()' id='getitemsbutton' class='button' type='button'>Get Items</button>
        <button id='clearbutton' class='button' type='reset'>Clear</button>
        <button id='queuebutton' class='button' type='submit'>Send to Queue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: AAAAH.  You're amazing.

The dynamic name generation was the part that I just couldn't figure out how to execute.  Glad to know I was at least in the ballpark on this, though!  Thank you SO much for your help!